# FOSUserBundle - PHPUnit - Mock a user

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit, fosuserbundle, symfony3.x

I am using Symfony with the FOSUserBundle and now I like to test some things like:

- Doctrine lifecycle
- Controller behind firewall

For those tests I need to be a specific user or at least in a user group.
How do I mock a user session so that ...

- The lifecycle field like "createdAt" will use the logged in user
- The Controller act like some mocked user is logged in

Example:

```
class FooTest extends ... {
    function setUp() {
        $user = $this->getMock('User', ['getId', 'getName']);

        $someWhereGlobal->user = $user;

        // after this you should be logged in as a mocked user
        // all operations should run using this user.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would do in this case is to create a `CustomWebTestCase` which extends the Symfony `WebTestCase`. In the class I would create a method which does the authentication for me.

Here is an example code:

```
namespace Company\MyBundle\Classes;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;

abstract class CustomWebTestCase extends WebTestCase
{

    /**
     * @param array|null $roles
     * @return \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client
     */
    protected static function createAuthenticatedClient(array $roles = null) {
        // Assign default user roles if no roles have been passed.
        if($roles == null) {
            $role = new Role('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN');
            $roles = array($role);
        } else {
            $tmpRoles = array();
            foreach($roles as $role)
            {
                $role = new Role($role, $role);
                $tmpRoles[] = $role;
            }
            $roles = $tmpRoles;
        }

        $user = new User('test_super_admin', 'passwd', $roles);

        return self::createAuthentication(static::createClient(), $user);
    }

    private static function createAuthentication(Client $client, User $user) {
        // Read below regarding config_test.yml!
        $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');

        // Authenticate
        $firewall = 'user_area'; // This  MUST MATCH the name in your security.firewalls.->user_area<-
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewall, $user->getRoles());
        $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        // Save authentication
        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);

        return $client;
    }
}
```

The code above will directly create a valid user session and will skip the firewall entirely. Therefore you can create whatever `$user` you want and it will still be valid. The important part of the code is located in the method `createAuthentication`. This is what does the authentication magic.

One more thing worth mentioning - make sure you have set `framework.session.storage_id` to `session.storage.mock_file` in your `config_test.yml` so that Symfony will automatically mock sessions instead of you having to deal with that in each test case:

```
framework:
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
```

Now in your test case you would simply extend `MyWebTestCase` and call the `createAuthenticatedClient()` method:

```
class MyTest extends CustomWebTestCase {
    public function testSomething() {
        //Create authoried and unauthorized clients.
        $authenticatedClient = self::createAuthenticatedClient(array("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"));
        $unauthorizedClient = self::createAuthenticatedClient(array("ROLE_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS"));

        // Check if the page behaves properly when the user doesn't have necessary role(s).
        $unauthorizedClient->request('GET', '/secured-page');
        $response = $unauthorizedClient->getResponse();
        $this->assertFalse($response->isSuccessful());
        $this->assertEquals(403, $response->getStatusCode(), "This request should have failed!");

        // Check if the page behaves properly when the user HAS the necessary role(s)
        $authenticatedClient->request('GET', '/secured-page');
        $response = $authenticatedClient->getResponse();
        $this->assertTrue($response->isSuccessful());
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode(), "This request should be working!");
    }
}
```

You can see an example in the Symfony [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html) as well.

Comment: Brilliant! "The code above will directly create a valid user session and will skip the firewall entirely." This is the way it should be mocked. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle). Once you have installed and configured the Bundle, creating and user and log in in tests is easy.

## Create a fixture for your user

This creates a user which will be loaded during tests:

```
<?php
// Filename: DataFixtures/ORM/LoadUserData.php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User;

class LoadUserData extends AbstractFixture implements FixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user
            ->setId(1)
            ->setName('foo bar')
            ->setEmail('foo@bar.com')
            ->setPassword('12341234')
            ->setAlgorithm('plaintext')
            ->setEnabled(true)
            ->setConfirmationToken(null)
        ;
        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();

        // Create a reference for this user.
        $this->addReference('user', $user);
    }
}
```

If you want to use groups of users, you can see the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures).

## Log in as this user in your test

As explained in [LiipFunctionalTestBundle's documentation](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle#logging-in-a-user-using-webtestcaseloginas), here is how to load the user in the database and log in as this user:

```
/**
 * Log in as the user defined in the Data Fixture.
 */
public function testWithUserLoggedIn()
{
    $fixtures = $this->loadFixtures(array(
        'Acme\MyBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUserData',
    ));

    $repository = $fixtures->getReferenceRepository();

    // Get the user from its reference.
    $user = $repository->getReference('user')

    // You can perform operations on this user.
    // ...

    // And perform functional tests:

    // Create a new Client which will be logged in.
    $this->loginAs($user, 'YOUR_FIREWALL_NAME');
    $this->client = static::makeClient();

    // The user is logged in: do whatever you want.
    $path = '/';
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', $path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with LiipFunctionalTestBundle which authorize you lot of shortcut for create Unit Test.

If already you have a form user for create or edit you can use this for your test unit workflow user in your application :

use the makeClient method for logging test

```
$credentials = array(
    'username' => 'a valid username',
    'password' => 'a valid password'
);

$client = static::makeClient($credentials);
```

use your form for test your creation

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/profile');

$form = $crawler->selectButton('adding')->form();
$form['fos_user_profile_form[firstName]'] = 'Toto';
$form['fos_user_profile_form[lastName]'] = 'Tata';
$form['fos_user_profile_form[username]'] = 'dfgdgdgdgf';
$form['fos_user_profile_form[email]'] = 'testfgdf@grgreger.fr';
$form['fos_user_profile_form[current_password]'] = 'gfgfgdgpk5dfgddf';
```

testing "createdAt" with just call findOneBy in repository user like this

```
$user = $this->getObjectManager()
             ->getRepository('AcmeSecurityBundle:User')
             ->findOneBy(array('username' => 'testCreateUserUsername'));

$this->assertTrue($user->getCreatedAt() == now());
```

Comment: Hello. This is a solution if I have a user or credentials. But it always has the overhead of logging in via form. I am searching for a solution where the user is just mocked or logged in already. The question has been updated with an example.